# Save window data - WSO2 CEP

Tags: window, wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I am using unique windows. I want to save the window state or data. because when CEP restart window data will be lost. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a persistence or HA mode deployment

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+CEP+4.0.0#ClusteringCEP4.0.0-Persistencemodedeployment